# google app scripts protections going away when copying sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a google sheet that has many protected ranges/cells.  It is currently set up so that myself and two others have full edit access to the workbook/protected ranges/cells.   All others accessing the sheet can then only edit certain cells.   It works exactly how I expect.

However, when I use a script to copy that sheet and insert data, the protections for the other two full editors goes away.   I do not remove protections in my code at all just add data to the sheet.

Any thoughts on why this would happen or how to fix it?     Again, these two other users can access the sheet they just can no longer edit any cell/range.

Comment: Perhaps the code itself is not doing it but the way that you deployed it is doing it

Comment: In order to confirm your current issue, can you provide the script of `when I use a script to copy that sheet and insert data, the protections for the other two full editors goes away.`. By this, I would like to confirm your current issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (sheetname should be the name of your sheet to copy):

```
function duplicateSheetWithProtections() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  sheet = ss.getSheetByName('sheetname');
  sheet2 = sheet.copyTo(ss).setName('My Copy'); 
  var protections = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
    var p = protections[i];
    var rangeNotation = p.getRange().getA1Notation();
    var p2 = sheet2.getRange(rangeNotation).protect();
    p2.setDescription(p.getDescription());
    p2.setWarningOnly(p.isWarningOnly());
    if (!p.isWarningOnly()) {
      p2.removeEditors(p2.getEditors());
      p2.addEditors(p.getEditors());
      // p2.setDomainEdit(p.canDomainEdit()); //  only if using an Apps domain 
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).